# How can I insert a variable into an XML Literals comment section and have it evaluated?

Tags: xml, vb.net

How can I get the variable My.Application.Info.Version.ToString to populate in the comments section?

```
    Dim Customers As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
                                 <!--Application Version: <%= My.Application.Info.Version.ToString %>-->
                                 <customers>
                                     <customer>
                                         <LastName>Jones</LastName>
                                     </customer>
                                     <customer>
                                         <LastName>Baggins</LastName>
                                         <FirstName>Billbo</FirstName>
                                     </customer>
                                     <customer>
                                         <LastName>Baggins</LastName>
                                         <FirstName>Frodo</FirstName>
                                     </customer>
                                     <customer>
                                         <LastName>Kurata</LastName>
                                         <FirstName>Deborah</FirstName>
                                     </customer>
                                 </customers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the comment like this

```
Dim Customers As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
                     <customers>
                         <customer>
                             <LastName>Jones</LastName>
                         </customer>
                         <customer>
                             <LastName>Baggins</LastName>
                             <FirstName>Billbo</FirstName>
                         </customer>
                         <customer>
                             <LastName>Baggins</LastName>
                             <FirstName>Frodo</FirstName>
                         </customer>
                         <customer>
                             <LastName>Kurata</LastName>
                             <FirstName>Deborah</FirstName>
                         </customer>
                     </customers>

Customers.Root.AddBeforeSelf(New XComment("Application Version: " & My.Application.Info.Version.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to disassemble this code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim doc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                           <!--Application Version: VERSION HERE-->
                           <SEPUnits></SEPUnits>

    doc.Save("test.xml")
End Sub
```

You would see that VB is just doing some of the work for you:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim VB$t_ref$S0 As New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing), Nothing)
    VB$t_ref$S0.Add(New XComment("Application Version: VERSION HERE"))
    Dim VB$t_ref$S1 As New XElement(XName.Get("SEPUnits", ""))
    VB$t_ref$S1.Add("")
    VB$t_ref$S0.Add(VB$t_ref$S1)
    VB$t_ref$S0.Save("test.xml")
End Sub
```

I'm new to XML literals, so there may be an easy trick to insert an XComment into your XML, or you can just build the XML like they do in C#:

```
Dim version As String = "1.0.0.1"
Dim doc As New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing), New XComment("Application Version: " & Version), New XElement("customers"))
```

Doc.ToString would display as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!-- Application Version: 1.0.0.1--> 
<customers />
```